# Is it okay to save the whole user response dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm new to dialogflow. And I want to create this bot that save the whole sentences of user response. I'm using `@sys.any` to save the whole sentences, because that's the only thing that work so far.
Is there any better way to save the reply instead of using `@sys.any`?

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to just save the whatever the user says. For example I am saying to my bot *i need a room from tomorrow to friday*. Then I can get this whole sentence from the fulfillment request iteself:

Below is the fulfillment request send to my webhook when I say the above mentioned sentence:

```
{
  "responseId": "27e88210-7912-495f-b6c6-ef20849a3843",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "i need a room from tomorrow to friday",
    "parameters": {
      "date_range": {
        "startDate": "2019-03-03T12:00:00+05:30",
        "endDate": "2019-03-08T16:28:22+05:30"
      },
      "number": ""
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/tulsi-75e50/agent/intents/4ade3d5c-8eed-4213-bb8e-0018a1b7c79e",
      "displayName": "book.date_range"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "payload": {}
  },
  "session": "projects/tulsi-75e50/agent/sessions/6f1d7bf0-5485-a63c-e6c0-5ab4fdb49247"
}
```

Here you can see that the `queryText` in the request holds the entire message that was said by the user. You can save this. No need to use `@sys.any`

And as for the question whether its okay to save, well that really depends on what you want to do, If you have a requirement that need you to save the whole sentence that users says, you can do that no problem.